# Fill javascript arrays from html form

Tags: javascript, plsql

I have a PLSQL form with multiple duplicate elements. example:
row1 - name, number, address
row2 - name, number, address
row3 - name, number, address

Is there a way to collect each row name into a javascript array then each row number into the second array, etc. Then send the values as an array to the PLSQL procedure to process each transaction to the DB.

```
function(){
  var name = [document.getElementById("name").value];
  var number = [document.getElementById("number").value];
  var address = [document.getElementById("address").value];

window.location.href = https://server/schema.package.procedure?name="+name+"&number="+number+"&address="+address+"";
```

}

Comment: Please share your html.

Comment: It is a ton of code. But to give you a better idea:

    '<form name=f_grid id="f_grid" method=post action="inservice.pkg_position_control.p_process">
<table>
    cursor loop
     <input id="name">
     <input id="number">
     <input id="address">
    end loop;
    </table>'
There are 200+ records that print to the page which each input can be updated to then save.